# In Corda, querying for a state based on a custom schema field in Java

Tags: corda

In Corda, I want to query the node's vault based on a custom schema field.

For example, in the [Example CorDapp](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example), I want to query for IOUs based on their value.

How can I perform this query in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the same [Example CorDapp](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example), here's an RPC client that queries a node's vault for IOUs that have a value of 99:

```
public class ExampleClientRPC {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final NetworkHostAndPort nodeAddress = NetworkHostAndPort.parse("localhost:10005");
        final CordaRPCClient client = new CordaRPCClient(nodeAddress, CordaRPCClientConfiguration.DEFAULT);
        final CordaRPCConnection connection = client.start("user1", "test");
        final CordaRPCOps proxy = connection.getProxy();

        CordaX500Name partyBName = new CordaX500Name("PartyB", "London", "GB");
        Party partyB = proxy.wellKnownPartyFromX500Name(partyBName);

        try {
            proxy.startFlowDynamic(ExampleFlow.Initiator.class, 97, partyB).getReturnValue().get();
            proxy.startFlowDynamic(ExampleFlow.Initiator.class, 98, partyB).getReturnValue().get();
            proxy.startFlowDynamic(ExampleFlow.Initiator.class, 99, partyB).getReturnValue().get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        QueryCriteria generalCriteria = new QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED);
        Field valueField = null;
        try {
            valueField = IOUSchemaV1.PersistentIOU.class.getDeclaredField("value");
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        QueryCriteria iouQuery = new VaultCustomQueryCriteria(Builder.equal(valueField, 99));
        generalCriteria = generalCriteria.and(iouQuery);

        List<StateAndRef<IOUState>> results = proxy.vaultQueryBy(generalCriteria,
                new PageSpecification(1,  10),
                new Sort(Collections.emptySet()),
                IOUState.class).getStates();

        for (StateAndRef<IOUState> result : results) {
            System.out.println(result);
        }

        connection.notifyServerAndClose();
    }
}
```